# Cannot disable three finger tap look up after migrating to a new computer

Tags: trackpad, preferences, dictionary, look-up

I recently moved to a new MacbookPro and migrated my old computer's files/settings over to the new one.

For some reason I am unable to disable the ability to look up the definition to a word by using a three finger tap gesture.

- I have unchecked the "Look up" option in the Trackpad preference
  pane.
- I also disabled option to "Look Up in Dictionary" within Keyboard
  preference pane > Keyboard Shortcuts > Searching > Look Up in
  Dictionary.

I typically use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to turn a three finger tap gesture into a middle click, I have disabled this feature for now and continue to have the issue where if I tap something with three fingers the text becomes highlighted and I am greeted with a definition to the word.  This happens in all applications.

Is there any other way to disable this feature?  Is there a terminal command I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop I migrated from was a Macbook Air that was running OSX 10.8.2.  When I migrated over to my new Macbook Pro 13" with Retina - the Retina only had 10.8.1 installed.  I learned that the update to 10.8.2 had been pulled after initially being released by apple because of misc issues on a few of their models - my 13" Retina included.

**Apple *re-released* a 10.8.2 version of OSX today that repaired my issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist` or running `defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture -bool false`?

Comment: I found the file and deleted it.  Did not help.  Even after I tried setting the settings to the desired false.  I even tried the terminal command - when I view my trackpad settings they appear to be how I want them (this feature set to false), but I still get the ability to do so when I three finger tap.

Comment: wanted to echo Ecnalyr's experience. These commands sure *look* like they should work, but they don't work.  Perhaps somebody else knows the correct setting names for these defaults?